# Create dictionary in a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a dictionary in a loop. Also, I would like to name each element in the dictionary using the loop.

```
table = {}

elasticity = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
elasticity.shape

genders = ['female', 'male']
income = ['i0','i1']

for i in range(len(genders)):
    for j in range(len(income)):
        key = genders[i]+"_"+income[j]
        table = ["key"=elasticity[i,j]]
```

I know I have an error in the last line somehow the "=" is wrong, but I can't fix it.

this is what I would like to have:

```
female_i0 = 1
female_i1 = 2

male_i0 = 3
male_i1 = 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve it for you, the problem lies within the assignment to the dictionary.

```
import numpy as np

elasticity = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
genders = ['female', 'male']
income = ['i0','i1']

table = {}
for i in range(len(genders)):
    for j in range(len(income)):
        key = genders[i]+"_"+income[j]
        table[key] = elasticity[i,j]
print(table)
```

The output is then:

```
{'female_i0': 1, 'female_i1': 2, 'male_i0': 3, 'male_i1': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since python 3.9 you can use the update operator:

```py
table = {}

elasticity = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
elasticity.shape

genders = ['female', 'male']
income = ['i0','i1']

for i in range(len(genders)):
    for j in range(len(income)):
        key = f"{genders[i]}_{income[j]}"
        table |= { key: elasticity[i,j]}
```

In this example I also use an f-string for key generation, that turned out to be the fastest option in a benchmark I made some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use dictionary comprehension to create the dictionary in one line:

```py
import numpy as np

elasticity = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

genders = ['female', 'male']
income = ['i0', 'i1']

table = {f"{gen}_{inc}": elasticity[i, j] for i, gen in enumerate(genders) for j, inc in enumerate(income)}

print(table)
```

Output:

```py
{'female_i0': 1, 'female_i1': 2, 'male_i0': 3, 'male_i1': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

With single dict comprehension:

```
table = {k:v for i, g in enumerate(genders) 
         for k, v in zip(map('_'.join, zip([g] * len(income), income)), elasticity[i])}
print(table)
```

---

```
{'female_i0': 1, 'female_i1': 2, 'male_i0': 3, 'male_i1': 4}
```